# Quickly change version of dependencies across many .NET Core project.json files

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I would like to modify version numbers of dependencies across many ASP.Net Core projects without manually having to edit each `project.json` file or waste precious time clicking in the NuGet Package Manager.

For example with ASP.Net Core 1.0.1 now released, I would like to subsitute:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
```

with

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.*",
```

Comment: you can call  NuGet Package Manager on solution file, so package modifications can be done on all packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in a comment. You can use the solution explorer window's context menu to `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...`. From there you can update packages versions. This is the only way (besides using something like **Notepad ++** to replace values in multiple open files).

[image]

You will then get a bubble that shows the number of updates available, again solution wide. Simply update them.

[image]